# How to combine throttling with subscription in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a function that performs some communication with a server to report the current screen geometry, etc.

```
    function sendScreenLayout() { 
        logElementLocations(exp.getPageCoordinates());
    };
```

I subscribe this function to some events in my code like this:

```
viewModel.onLayoutChange.subscribe(sendScreenLayout);
$('#right-splitter > #mainContent').resize(sendScreenLayout);
$(window).resize(sendScreenLayout);
...
setTimeout(sendScreenLayout, 1);
```

Some of these events may get sent too frequently to be usefully handled by the server, and I would like to throttle the requests to some reasonable rate.

The best I could come up with was something like this:

```
var triggerSend = ko.observable();

ko.computed(function() {
    triggerSend();
    logElementLocations(exp.getPageCoordinates());
}).extend({throttle: 200});

function sendScreenLayout() {
    triggerSend.valueHasMutated();
}
```

Is there a more succinct way of capturing this pattern, or is this the way to go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), you could use [`debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) like this:

```
var sendScreenLayout = _.debounce(function() { 
    logElementLocations(exp.getPageCoordinates());
}, 200);
...
$(window).resize(sendScreenLayout);
...
```

Otherwise, it's not really a pattern that Knockout supports directly. The solution you came up seems good enough, although here's an alternative:

```
var triggerSend = ko.computed({
    read: function() {},
    write: function(dummy) {
        logElementLocations(exp.getPageCoordinates());
    }
}).extend({throttle: 200});

function sendScreenLayout() {
    triggerSend(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `viewModel.onLayoutChange` is an observable, you can simply do:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    viewModel.onLayoutChange(); //implicitly subscribes this callback to changes
    logElementLocations(exp.getPageCoordinates());
}).extend({throttle: 200});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is quite elegant! I have a list that has to be sorted, the order and what by then needs to be saved to the server as a user preference. I want to update the server on 3 different property changes but not on every change. doing something like this.

```
ko.computed(function () {
    self.sort.direction();
    self.sort.order();
    self.sort.groupByPIC();

    if (!_firstLoad) {
        _dataService.updateSortPreferences({
            model : new _jsSortModel(self.sort)
        });
    }
}).extend({ throttle: 2000 });
```

Allows me to subscript to a number of properties with one function and give the user time to stop clicking round before updating the server.

very nice, thank you!